# you already have an app with that package name

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I need help with flutter and firebase package name

I’m trying to add 3 android apps that are using the same backend server to firebase, I have managed to add 1 app and when I try to add the second one I’m getting this notification “ you already have an app with that package name” that is in firebase.

how do i go about it?

with the solutions I have found, I have to rename the 2nd and 3rd package name, but I don't seem to understand why I should that or the concept behind it.

Comment: What are the three different android package names you are using? It sounds like you are using the same android package for three different projects with no differentiation between them

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a different package name "com...XXX" in every project it's like your app's unique id.
you can change app name by following this steps

**Step 1**

Go to file **android/app/buil.gradle** in your flutter project

```
android{
  //make sure every project has different application ID
  defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.xyz" //change here               
    }
}
```

**Step 2:**

run commands

> flutter clean
>
> flutter pub get
>
> flutter run

**Step 3**

Remove your old project from firebase  and reconnect your new name project